# Increment number in text file

Tags: php

I want to record downloads in a text file

Someone comes to my site and downloads something, it will add a new row to the text file if it hasn't already or increment the current one.

I have tried

```
$filename = 'a.txt';
$lines    = file($filename);
$linea    = array();

foreach ($lines as $line) 
{ 
    $linea[] = explode("|",$line);
}

$linea[0][1] ++;

$a = $linea[0][0] . "|" . $linea[0][1];

file_put_contents($filename, $a);
```

but it always increments it by more than 1

The text file format is

```
 name|download_count
```

Comment: how many lines are there in your `.txt` file...??

Comment: post some sample content of your `txt` file

Comment: a db would be so much easier than a text file for this

Comment: You should really not be using a text file for this. Any solution will fail to take into account any sort of locking and a number of other things that are necessary for this to work reliably. If you just need something simple, use sqlite. It's a file-based sql-like database that will take care of everything for you.

Comment: @NuclearDog There's advisory locking in PHP, I don't see how that's a problem.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing your incrementing outside of the `for` loop, and only accessing the `[0]`th element so nothing is changing anywhere else.

This should probably look something like:

```
$filename = 'a.txt';
$lines = file($filename);

// $k = key, $v = value
foreach ($lines as $k=>$v) { 
    $exploded = explode("|", $v);

    // Does this match the site name you're trying to increment?
    if ($exploded[0] == "some_name_up_to_you") {
        $exploded[1]++;

        // To make changes to the source array,
        // it must be referenced using the key.
        // (If you just change $v, the source won't be updated.)
        $lines[$k] = implode("|", $exploded);
    }        
}

// Write.
file_put_contents($filename, $lines);
```

You should probably be using a database for this, though.  Check out PDO and MYSQL and you'll be on your way to awesomeness.

---

EDIT

To do what you mentioned in your comments, you can set a boolean flag, and trigger it as you walk through the array.  This may warrant a `break`, too, if you're only looking for one thing:

```
...
$found = false;
foreach ($lines as $k=>$v) { 
    $exploded = explode("|", $v);

    if ($exploded[0] == "some_name_up_to_you") {
        $found = true;
        $exploded[1]++;
        $lines[$k] = implode("|", $exploded);
        break; // ???
    }        
}

if (!$found) {
    $lines[] = "THE_NEW_SITE|1";
}

...
```

Comment: Great that works thank you, is there a way i can check if the line exits first and either increment or add the new line?

Comment: No problem, welcome to SO.  Give me a second to figure out what you said :)

Comment: Great, i normally use MySQL as the backend but im having problems with my host just now so im using text files until it gets sorted.

Comment: OK updated.  Yeah a database is the way to go (using PDO prepared statements if you're not already). Hope it works out for ya!

Comment: Great that works for one line though if there is more lines in the txt file the count wont register.

Comment: That's why the `break` is optional.  You may be looking for more than one name, so the `if` would have a few `||` conditions included, and the `break` would have to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

one hand you are using a `foreach` loop, another hand you are write only the first line into your file after storing it in `$a`... it's making me confuse what do you have in your `.txt` file...

Try this below code... hope it will solve your problem...

```
$filename = 'a.txt';
// get file contents and split it...
$data = explode('|',file_get_contents($filename));
// increment the counting number...
$data[1]++;
// join the contents...
$data = implode('|',$data);
file_put_contents($filename, $data);
```

Comment: I want it to have a new counter for each file per line

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating your own structure inside a text file, why not just use PHP arrays to keep track? You should also apply proper locking to prevent race conditions:

```
function recordDownload($download, $counter = 'default')
{
    // open lock file and acquire exclusive lock
    if (false === ($f = fopen("$counter.lock", "c"))) {
            return;
    }
    flock($f, LOCK_EX);

    // read counter data
    if (file_exists("$counter.stats")) {
            $stats = include "$counter.stats";
    } else {
            $stats = array();
    }

    if (isset($stats[$download])) {
        $stats[$download]++;
    } else {
        $stats[$download] = 1;
    }

    // write back counter data
    file_put_contents('counter.txt', '<?php return ' . var_export($stats, true) . '?>');

    // release exclusive lock
    fclose($f);
}

recordDownload('product1'); // will save in default.stats
recordDownload('product2', 'special'); // will save in special.stats
```

Comment: Because i need to sort the counters to display a Top downloads stat.

Comment: @BrendanMullan I'm sure you could write a shell script for that :) in any case, I hope the other parts of my answer covering the advisory locking helps.

Comment: @BrendanMullan I've updated my answer with a more generic solution; it keeps track of all download counts inside one file.

Answer (score 0):

personally i suggest using a json blob as the content of the text file. then you can read the file into php, decode it (json_decode), manipulate the data, then resave it.